# How to conditionally display decimals in a measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say I have a simple measure like this:

```
SimpleMeasure = MyTable[Column1]/MyTable[Column2]
```

Is it possible to have the number of displayed decimals dependent on the value?  For example, if my measure calculates the number 500, then I don't want to see 500.00 but rather 500. However if my measure calculates 0.56, then I want to see the value displayed like that to two decimal places and not rounded to the number 1.

So a possible visualization table would look like this:

```
Store   SimpleMeasure
00      10
01      18
02      0.67
03      6
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The number format can't be dynamically adjusted by a measure. You can control it on column/measure level in the designer. But you can change the result type of your measure to be text and format it the way you want. However you will lose the ability to have automatic totals and the dynamic formatting based on the user's locale.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, it isn't good datviz practice to mix different precisions. Numbers should all have the same number of decimal places when in a single column for easy comparison and alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF(
[SimpleMeasure] < 1, FORMAT([SimpleMeasure], "#,##0.##",
FORMAT([SimpleMeasure], "#,##0")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight edit to @Conner's answer correcting brackets:

```
IF([SimpleMeasure] < 1, FORMAT([SimpleMeasure], "#,##0.##"),
FORMAT([SimpleMeasure], "#,##0")
)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Switch() function. It will return the first True result. Put you values in a DESC order - start with the largest value, then come to a lower and then to the lowerest. For example :

```
Switch(
    True
    ,[SimpleMeasure]<1,Round([SimpleMeasure],2) -- 0.655->0.66
    ,[SimpleMeasure]>999,Round([SimpleMeasure],-2) --1044->1000
    ,[SimpleMeasure]>499,Round([SimpleMeasure],-1) -- 505,5->510
    ,[SimpleMeasure]>99,Round([SimpleMeasure],0)  -- 101,55->102        
    ,[SimpleMeasure]>1,Round([SimpleMeasure],1)  -- 99,43->99.4
)
```

Or/and you can use in the Switch() the Format() function, with or instead of Round() like:

```
Format([SimpleMeasure],"#,##0.#") 

Or
     
Format(Round([SimpleMeasure],1),"#,##0.#")

-- Both of them Format() will return  and show 99,43 as 99,4. 
-- Placeholer # returns a digit or nothing.
-- Placegholder 0 returns a digit or 0.
```

Usage of Format() and Round() depends on your task. But for a selective Fomat you will need the Switch().

Hope, the answer will help you solve the case

Comment: Your first suggestion simply did not work.  I also think we are confused on where a comma should go verses a decimal. Your second solution was actually almost it.  However, every number has a decimal at the end.  Example: (662.  instead of just 662). So what I did was an IF statement where if the measure < 1 then the format was "#,##0.##", else ""#,##0" and that worked. So thank you

Comment: Nice to be usefull ). Accually, I was confused with a statement that "The number format can't be dynamically adjusted ". I was in a hurry and and didn't check the post. Anyhow you've got the point and solved the issue.